# How to safely block a .NET thread

Tags: .net, multithreading, unit-testing, blocking

I have a class that raises an event after a specified time (it uses a `System.Timers.Timer` inside).  In my test code, I created a `Stopwatch` which I started before the class was created and set the callback for the event to stop that `Stopwatch`.  Then, I *blocked* until `Not Stopwatch.IsRunning`.  Simple, right?

My original blocking code was

```vb
While Stopwatch.IsRunning
End While
```

but I found that having an empty while loop like that never allowed my callback to fire!  As soon as I put debugging code into the while loop, it worked!:

```vb
Dim lastSecond As Integer = 0
While sw.IsRunning
    If (Date.Now.Second > lastSecond) Then
         lastSecond = Date.Now.Second
         Console.WriteLine("blocking...")
    End If
End While
```

What causes this strange behavior, and more importantly, what's the simplest code I can put into my blocking section that will allow the event to fire?

Comment: what version of .NET are you using?

Comment: 4.0 but I could switch to 4.5 relatively easily

Comment: then don't forget about Tasks, and in particular  await Task.Yield() which allow the message pump of the UI thread to run when called on the UI Thread, or await Task.Delay(delay) which will pause the execution without keeping the current thread blocked like Sleep. I won't elaborate, as the real answer to your question is really Hans one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
While Stopwatch.IsRunning
End While
```

It is one of the Great Sins in threading, called a "hot wait loop".  Threading has many sins, and many of them have no yellow tape at all, but this one is particularly insidious.  The principal problem is that you keep one processor core burning red hot, testing the IsRunning property in a tight loop.

This begets a very nasty problem when you use the x86 jitter, it generates code in the release build that reads the IsRunning property backing field variable in a cpu register.  And tests the cpu register value over and over again, without reloading the value from the field.  That's the ultimate deadlock, it can never exit the loop.  You bumped it out of that mode by editing the code or by using the debugger.  To avoid it, the backing field of the property must be declared *volatile* but that's not something you can do in VB.NET, nor is it the proper fix.

Instead you should use a proper synchronization object, one that lets you signal another thread that something happened.  A good one is the AutoResetEvent, you'd use it like this:

```
Dim IsCompleted As New AutoResetEvent(False)

Private Sub WaitForTimer()
    IsCompleted.WaitOne()
    ''etc..
End Sub

Private Sub timer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles timer.Elapsed
    IsCompleted.Set()
    timer.Stop()
End Sub
```

Beware that AutoResetEvent has yellow tape missing as well.  Calling Set() more than once while the other thread hasn't yet called WaitOne() ends up poorly.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "yellow tape"?

Comment: Ever seen an American crime show on TV like Law & Order?  The scene where the crime was committed is cordoned-off by yellow tape to prevent anybody from blundering in and destroy the evidence.  In other words: "pay attention, something unusual is going on here!"

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Sleep or Spin for this. look into signalling:

```
WaitHandle.WaitOne
```

> Blocks the current thread until the current WaitHandle receives a
>   signal, using a 32-bit signed integer to specify the time interval and
>   specifying whether to exit the synchronization domain before the wait.

Example:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts

<Synchronization(true)>
Public Class SyncingClass
    Inherits ContextBoundObject

    Private waitHandle As EventWaitHandle

    Public Sub New()
         waitHandle = New EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset)
    End Sub 

    Public Sub Signal()
        Console.WriteLine("Thread[{0:d4}]: Signalling...", Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode())
        waitHandle.Set()
    End Sub 

    Public Sub DoWait(leaveContext As Boolean)
        Dim signalled As Boolean

        waitHandle.Reset()
        Console.WriteLine("Thread[{0:d4}]: Waiting...", Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode())
        signalled = waitHandle.WaitOne(3000, leaveContext)
        If signalled Then
            Console.WriteLine("Thread[{0:d4}]: Wait released!!!", Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode())
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Thread[{0:d4}]: Wait timeout!!!", Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode())
        End If 
    End Sub 
End Class 

Public Class TestSyncDomainWait
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim syncClass As New SyncingClass()

        Dim runWaiter As Thread

        Console.WriteLine(vbNewLine + "Wait and signal INSIDE synchronization domain:" + vbNewLine)
        runWaiter = New Thread(AddressOf RunWaitKeepContext)
        runWaiter.Start(syncClass)
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Console.WriteLine("Thread[{0:d4}]: Signal...", Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode())
        ' This call to Signal will block until the timeout in DoWait expires.
        syncClass.Signal()
        runWaiter.Join()

        Console.WriteLine(vbNewLine + "Wait and signal OUTSIDE synchronization domain:" + vbNewLine)
        runWaiter = New Thread(AddressOf RunWaitLeaveContext)
        runWaiter.Start(syncClass)
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Console.WriteLine("Thread[{0:d4}]: Signal...", Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode())
        ' This call to Signal is unblocked and will set the wait handle to 
        ' release the waiting thread.
        syncClass.Signal()
        runWaiter.Join()
    End Sub 

    Public Shared Sub RunWaitKeepContext(parm As Object)
        Dim syncClass As SyncingClass = CType(parm, SyncingClass)
        syncClass.DoWait(False)
    End Sub 

    Public Shared Sub RunWaitLeaveContext(parm As Object)
        Dim syncClass As SyncingClass = CType(parm, SyncingClass)
        syncClass.DoWait(True)
    End Sub 
End Class 

' The output for the example program will be similar to the following: 
' 
' Wait and signal INSIDE synchronization domain: 
' 
' Thread[0004]: Waiting... 
' Thread[0001]: Signal... 
' Thread[0004]: Wait timeout!!! 
' Thread[0001]: Signalling... 
' 
' Wait and signal OUTSIDE synchronization domain: 
' 
' Thread[0006]: Waiting... 
' Thread[0001]: Signal... 
' Thread[0001]: Signalling... 
' Thread[0006]: Wait released!!!
```

See more details here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy257t0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding

```
Thread.Sleep(0)
```

in your tight loop.

Comment: That works, but... If it's `sleeping` for `0`, what would that actually accomplish?

Comment: Your empty loop probably got compiled out, so it never got executed, the sleep for 0 will (should) stay compiled in but shouldn't cost you any sleep time

Comment: Sleep(0) will give up the rest of the time-slice given to your thread, allowing other threads to do work.  You cold also sleep for  a short time.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need active waiting, you can use [SpinWait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinwait.aspx) structure.

And reason why your empty loop didn't work could be because JIT during compilation saw that this loop is empty, and optimized your code by removing it (just guessing).

Comment: The program hangs indefinitely when the loop is empty, so it's definitely not optimized out.

Comment: My apologies, i misunderstood your code behavior then. Other explanation might be, that `Console.Writeline` performs I/O operation which allows the second (timer) thread to do it works. If your main thread (one where) you're making your `while` loop has higher priority then Timer's thread, and it doesn't give him any time slices to execute the callback? But probably using approach that @Abdias Software suggested rather then SpinWait or Thread.Sleep would be the best.